# C - segfault when I do "cmd | cmd | cmd ; exit"

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault, recode

I have to recode a shell in C and when i'm try to do, for example, `ls | ls | ls ; exit`, I have a Segmentation fault. (malloc.c:3630: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long)(size) >= (unsigned long)(nb)' failed.
Aborted)

My exit was running before the end of my `ls | ls | ls` but if there are only 1 pipe its work.
If you have an idea, or you want more information please tell me.

Here the functions for exec a (multi) pipe:

```
void            exec_pipe(char *multi)
{
  char          **cmd;
  int           *pfd;
  int           pn;
  int           status;
  int           i;

  pfd = NULL;
  i = 0;
  pn = count_pipe(multi);
  cmd = my_str_to_wordtabpipe(multi);
  pfd = init_pfd(pfd, pn);
  exec_pipe_cmd(pfd, pn, cmd);
  close_pfd(pfd, pn);
  while (i < pn + 1)
    {
      wait(&status);
      i++;
    }
  destroy_tabstr(&cmd);
  free(pfd);
}

void            exec_pipe_cmd(int *pfd, int pn, char **cmd)
{
  int           i;
  int           j;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  while (cmd[i])
    {
      if (cmd[i][0] == '~')
        if (!(cmd[i] = put_home(cmd[i])))
          my_e_printf("No $HOME variable set.\n");
      if (cmd[i])
        cmd[i] = get_alias(cmd[i]);
      fork_pipe(&cmd[i], pfd, pn, j);
      j += 2;
      i++;
    }
}

void            dup_pipe(char **cmd, int *pfd, int j)
{
  if (*(cmd + 1))
    if (dup2(pfd[j + 1], 1) < 0)
      exit(-1);
  if (j != 0)
    if (dup2(pfd[j - 2], 0) < 0)
      exit(-1);
}

void            fork_pipe(char **cmd, int *pfd, int pn, int j)
{
  char          **tmp;
  pid_t         pid;
  char          *path;

  tmp = my_str_to_wordtab(cmd[0]);
  if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
      path = get_cmd_path(tmp[0]);
      if (my_strcmp(path, tmp[0]) == 0 && path[0] != '.'
          && path[0] != '~' && path[0] != '/')
        path = NULL;
      dup_pipe(cmd, pfd, j);
      close_pfd(pfd, pn);
      if (exec_builtins(tmp))
        exit(0);
      else if (!path || execve(path, tmp, g_env) == -1)
        {
          my_e_printf("%s: Command not found.\n", tmp[0]);
          exit(-1);
        }
    }
  destroy_tabstr(&tmp);
}
int             count_pipe(char *str)
{
  int           k;
  int           i;

  i = 0;
  k = 0;
  while (str[i])
    {
      if (str[i] == '|')
        k++;
      i++;
    }
  return (k);
}

int             *init_pfd(int *pfd, int pn)
{
  int           i;

  i = 0;
  if ((pfd = malloc(sizeof(int) * (pn * 2))) == NULL)
    exit(-1);
  while (i < pn)
    {
      if (pipe(pfd + i * 2) < 0)
    my_printf("An error occured when pipe creation\n");
      i++;
    }
  return (pfd);
}

void            close_pfd(int *pfd, int pn)
{
  int           i;

  i = 0;
  while (i < 2 * pn)
    {
      close(pfd[i]);
      i++;
    }
}
int             count_pipe(char *str)
{
  int           k;
  int           i;

  i = 0;
  k = 0;
  while (str[i])
    {
      if (str[i] == '|')
        k++;
      i++;
    }
  return (k);
}

int             *init_pfd(int *pfd, int pn)
{
  int           i;

  i = 0;
  if ((pfd = malloc(sizeof(int) * (pn * 2))) == NULL)
    exit(-1);
  while (i < pn)
    {
      if (pipe(pfd + i * 2) < 0)
    my_printf("An error occured when pipe creation\n");
      i++;
    }
  return (pfd);
}

void            close_pfd(int *pfd, int pn)
{
  int           i;

  i = 0;
  while (i < 2 * pn)
    {
      close(pfd[i]);
      i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to actually locate the crash.

Comment: i know why it crashes but i don't know how to resolve it : my "ls | ls | ls" is not finish when my exit start

Comment: You do [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for your child processes to exit before running the next command?

Comment: yes, i have a char * with "pn" pipe, i execute them in a loop with the fork and after that i have this :
  while (i < pn + 1)
    {
      wait(&status);
      i++;
    }

Comment: You really need to show some actual (and relevant) code. Please edit your question, and preferably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: its hard to post a verifiable example, they is too much code line

Comment: Note that there is little point in the particular pipeline you've chosen; `ls` does not read standard input.  However, it should still be possible to run the code without crashing — even if the net result is the same as simply running `ls`.

Comment: i have resolve the problem, it was an alias problem, not pipeline.
sorry for the inconvenience !